# DBSCAN producing strange results on a ship's location dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, geospatial

The dataset is composed of about 10K points representing the coordinates of a ship: https://pastebin.pl/view/86b44fe9

DBSCAN is used to cluster the points:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

file = open("86b44fe9.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
x = []
for p in lines:
    poi = p.rstrip("\n").split(" ")
    x.append([float(poi[2]), float(poi[3])])

# Parameters of DBSCAN
min_samples = 42
eps = 0.001 

dbscan = DBSCAN(eps, min_samples).fit(x) # fitting the model
labels = dbscan.labels_

out_file = open("clusters.txt", "w")    
for p in range(len(lines)):
    poi = lines[p].rstrip("\n").split(" ")
    out_file.write(poi[0] + " ")
    out_file.write(poi[1] + " ")
    out_file.write(str(labels[p]))
    out_file.write("\n")
    
out_file.close()
```

This would produce many anomalous points that are visualized in yellow. The ones displayed within red-boxes do not make sense to me. The one in the middle has an id of *10248558*, which can observed in the output file *clusters.txt*.

I am not sure whether it is because Euclidean distance is used instead of perhaps Haversine distance? Yet, I don't think this is the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html):

> **eps**: The maximum distance between two samples for one
> to be considered as in the neighborhood of the other. This is not a
> maximum bound on the distances of points within a cluster. This is the
> most important DBSCAN parameter to choose appropriately for your data
> set and distance function.
>
> **min_samples**:  The number of samples (or total weight) in a
> neighborhood for a point to be considered as a core point. This
> includes the point itself.

You should play with the number of samples a littel to avoid that?
If you read about the function of [dbscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). Dbscan is strong to identify core points.
[image]
In this diagram, min_sample = 4. Point A and the other red points are core points, because the area surrounding these points in an 0,5 = epsilon radius contain at least 4 points (including the point itself). Because they are all reachable from one another, they form a single cluster.
Points B and C are not core points, but are reachable from A (via other core points) and thus belong to the cluster as well. Point N is a noise point that is neither a core point nor directly-reachable).

In your case there is not really noisy data and this it while the labels are "unlogical". You could try kmeans? Maybe thats a better choice for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Playing with the numbers solves the problem. However, I think there is some sort of logic error in the DBSCAN function as those points should not be labelled as an "anomaly".

Comment: its not anomaly, they belong to a different cluster, there are many points next to them, so the conditions are satisfied

Comment: Yes indeed, those points should not be an anomaly but it is labelled as such.

Comment: its not labbeled as anomaly, you have 2 strongs classes, there is no anomaly